# jquery keydown animate background color

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simply animate the background on a keystroke.  I can't get it to work using:

```
$('input#userInput').live('keydown', function() { 
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#4E1402'}, 300).delay(800).animate({backgroundColor: '#555'}, 100);
});
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: ok, I see what everyone is saying about jquery UI...let's just use color for example...is the code correct then for color?  I can't get that!  http://jsfiddle.net/6k6uK/

Comment: I included a jsFiddle in my answer that uses your exact code with the jQuery.color() plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you [can't animate background-color](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) without a plugin

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality **(For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used)**. Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

[jsFiddle with the plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/cAbRg/1/)

Comment: @webwrks - Appologies... forgot to hit the update button after I added the plugin. Should be working now. I updated the link.

Comment: thanks!  I liked the yo! touch but was wondering too.  I wonder if this is something jQuery will ever make possible w/out the UI.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$('#userInput').keydown(function(){
  $(this).css("backgroundColor",'#4E1402');
$(this).delay(2000).queue(function(){
    $(this).css("backgroundColor",'#555');});
 });
```

Comment: @Gautam3164 - There is nothing wrong with his syntax... jQuery simply doesn't support animating background-color using the core library.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [color](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin, which "Adds the ability to do color animations to jQuery 1.2, and newer."

Also, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) already includes color animation support.